# Adding Kinect cursor events to WPF Controls (Kinect SDK 1.7)

Tags: c#, wpf, events, kinect, arcgis

I´m writing a Kinect WPF application with some special WPF controls (ESRI WPF – especially map control)

Is there any option how to add to this control my own event which will be fired when the hand cursor do something? For example: *HandEnter, HandLeave*, etc.

I´m not experienced with Events in C# - I´ve never created my own Events – I only know, that there is an AddEvent and AddEventRoute for WPF controls – is this the right way?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at [KinectInteraction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn188671.aspx) in the Kinect for Windows Toolkit 1.7, which supports tracking hands in a physical interaction zone, etc.

However, from your post it seems like it would be a better idea to read up on and experiment with the basics of events and event handling in C# and WPF first. These articles on MSDN may serve as a starting point:

1. [Events (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx)
2. [Events tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)
3. [Events (WPF)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753115.aspx)